# Limit the number of resources (forklifts) used in tasks

Tags: anylogic

I have pallets shipments arrive at a warehouse. Once the arrive, forklifts are used to unload then and move the shipments to storage units. The current capacity of the forklift pool is 50. What happens now that when pallets arrive with a number of shipments to be unloaded and stored, let's say 10 shipments, then ten forklifts go to the pallets and unload the 10 shipments at once. Since the flowchart a pallet arrives and a forklift is seized consequently. I want to have one of two forklifts to be associated with a pallet at until all shipments are unloaded. I tried to use restricted Area Start and End between the forklift seize block and the shipment moveTo block but that limited the number of forklifts assigned to all pallets not only the one at the time.

Thank you

Comment: "I want to have one of two forklifts to be associated with a pallet at until all shipments are unloaded." --> Can you clarify? Not sure I understand this. Also, a screenshot would help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot, so i will just give you the hints necessary to do what you want

step 1. You need for each pallet to have a variable associated with that shipment. This varaiable can be an id integer, or maybe a variable of type Shipment.

step 2. Then on the on seize block, you have to specify a custom resource selection that defines the forklift you can use for that pallet. It would be either a forklift that is already assigned to that shipment, or a forklift that is free and no other forklift is connected to that shipment... here the logic depends on your own case and on how many forklifts should be used per shipment

step 3. When the resource is chosen, You connect that resource to your shipment through a variable or through a link to agents, if that resource was not previously connected to it.

step 4. When there are no more pallets available, you disconnect the forklift from the shipment so you have a new forklift free for any new shipment coming through